# Funny C syntax issue x ->

Tags: c

I'm not clear on some of the syntax inside of this structure.
Can someone please explain the following `x->` portion of the code. What does that do? Is that another way of dereferencing?

```
void rectangle_init(t_rectangle *x)
{
    x->x0=-1;
    x->y0=-1;
    x->x1=1;
    x->y1=1;
}
```

Comment: It's syntactic sugar for `(*x).x0`.

Comment: There is also "-->"  Example: int a=10;while(a-->0) printf("%i\n",a); Funny?

Comment: @tugrul: thats 2 operators, not one.

Comment: @Tom Tanner: no it is one --> operator

Comment: That is the same as `while (a-- > 0)`. There is no --> operator.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: There is no `-->` operator. Don't give misinformation to someone that's trying to learn.

Comment: while( a --> 0 )   makes a count down each iteration

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: Again, there is no `-->` operator. That code is the post-decrement operator (`--`) followed by the greater than operator (`>`).

Comment: ok i understood it. Thanks. But it looks like "a approaches 0 "

Comment: So, a++<10 could work the same way ?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: Yes, the "goes down to" operator is a programmer joke. Unfortunately it confuses people new to the language.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık you give me a sad, sir

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `->` operator is a shorthand for dereferencing and accessing a member; when you write

```
x->x0
```

it's exactly as if you wrote

```
(*x).x0
```

The shorthand was introduced because it happens often to access members of `struct`s via pointers, and the "original" syntax looks unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

In general: 
when you have a pointer like *x in your case and you want to change an element in x, use x->xxx = ...
If it is not a pointer (e.g. y) then use y.xxx = ...